# R: Filter two data.frames for duplicated values in two columns and by groups

Tags: r, filter, compare, subset

I have a data.frame `dat` which stores my normal data and groups are defined by `ID`.

```
data <- structure(list(NAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("NAME1", "NAME2"), class = "factor"), ID = c(23L, 23L, 57L), REF_YEAR = c(1920L, 1938L, 1869L), SURV_YEAR = c(1938L, 1962L, 1872L), VALUE = c(20L, 40L, 34L)), .Names = c("NAME", "ID", "REF_YEAR", "SURV_YEAR","VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

  NAME  ID REF_YEAR SURV_YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1 23     1920      1938    20
2 NAME1 23     1938      1962    40
3 NAME2 57     1869      1872    34
```

And I have a second `data.frame`, `dat_q` which I would like to compare to `dat`

```
dat_q <- structure(list(NAME = structure(1:2, .Label = c("NAME1", "NAME2"), class = "factor"), ID = c(23L, 57L), REF_YEAR = c(1934L, 1866L), SURV_YEAR = c(1938L, 1868L), VALUE = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("NAME", "ID", "REF_YEAR", "SURV_YEAR", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

  NAME  ID REF_YEAR SURV_YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1 23     1934      1938     A
2 NAME2 57     1866      1868     B
```

**My question: How could I delete all rows in `dat_q` that contain an equal value in the columns `REF_YEAR` or `SURV_YEAR` than in the same columns of `dat` (in the sample data `1938`)? This should be applied by group (as defined by `ID`) and not over the whole `data.frame`**

In the end, using my sample data this would be the result coming from filtering `dat_q`

```
  NAME  ID REF_YEAR SURV_YEAR VALUE
2 NAME2 57     1866      1868     B
```

**EDIT**

Here is some other sample data with which the code provided by @thelatemail won't work. And I can't figure out why, `dat_q` should be filtered out, because it contains an exact same value than `dat`.

```
data <- structure(list(NAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "NAME1", class = "factor"), ID = c(226L, 226L, 226L), SURV_YEAR = c(2009L, 2010L, 2012L), REF_YEAR = c(2008L, 2009L, 2011L), VALUE = c(-7L, -37L,  -51L)), .Names = c("NAME", "ID", "SURV_YEAR", "REF_YEAR", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

   NAME  ID SURV_YEAR REF_YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1 226      2009     2008    -7
2 NAME1 226      2010     2009   -37
3 NAME1 226      2012     2011   -51

dat_q <- structure(list(NAME = structure(1L, .Label = "NAME1", class = "factor"), ID = 226L, REF_YEAR = 2010L, SURV_YEAR = 2011L, VALUE = structure(1L, .Label = "-X", class = "factor")), .Names = c("NAME", "ID", "REF_YEAR", "SURV_YEAR", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

  NAME   ID REF_YEAR SURV_YEAR VALUE
1 NAME1 226     2010      2011    -X
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like `by` in base R for figuring out the logic of this sort of problem. This works, but may be a bit slow:

```
do.call(rbind,by(
  dat_q,
  dat_q$ID,
  function(x) {
    subdata <- data[data$ID==x$ID,]
    x[!(x$REF_YEAR %in% subdata$REF_YEAR | x$SURV_YEAR %in% subdata$SURV_YEAR),]
  }
))

#    NAME ID REF_YEAR SURV_YEAR VALUE
#57 NAME2 57     1866      1868     B
```

A `data.table` solution following the same logic may be quicker:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat_q)
setDT(data)
dat_q[
     ,
     .SD[!(REF_YEAR   %in% data$REF_YEAR[data[,ID==.BY]] | 
           SURV_YEAR  %in% data$SURV_YEAR[data[,ID==.BY]])],
     by=ID
]

#   ID  NAME REF_YEAR SURV_YEAR VALUE
#1: 57 NAME2     1866      1868     B
```

---

With `data.table`, I think you can also do it this way. After converting to data.tables,

```
# using 1.9.3+, just remove `by=.EACHI` if you're using <= 1.9.2
setkey(data, ID)
setkey(dat_q, ID)

idx = data[dat_q, any(c(i.REF_YEAR, i.SURV_YEAR) %in% c(REF_YEAR, SURV_YEAR)), by=.EACHI]$V1
dat_q[!idx]
#     NAME ID REF_YEAR SURV_YEAR VALUE
# 1: NAME2 57     1866      1868     B
```

We perform a join, and on each matching rows of `data` corresponding to `dat_q`, on the key columns, we compute the expression in `j`. That gives us the logical value we need to index/subset `dat_q` later.

Comment: I don't think you need the `[data[,ID==.BY]]` part

Comment: @DavidArenburg - I need to limit the parts compared to the matching ids surely? References to `data` won't be automatically subsetted to the `by` groups.

Comment: Thank you @thelatemail! while this works for some of my data, I can't seem to figure out why it does not for everything in my data. I posted an edit and added new sample data with which it won't work. It should filter out `dat_q`, because 2011 is appearing in both data samples.

Comment: with @Arun's edit it worked for all data. I am using `data.table` version 1.9.2 Thank you very much!

Comment: @redshoe - in your second example you switch the names `REF_YEAR` and `SURV_YEAR` between the `data` and `dat_q`. There is no match between the variables because of this.